# STM32F407 and ST-LINK not compatible?

Tags: stm32

Without knowing how I should approach to STM32 development board, I purchased Olimex STM32-H407 which would work with OpenOCD.  and I purchased ST-LINK/V2 hoping that any JTAG cable would work.  My PC does not seems to understand ST-LINK + Olimex STM32-H407.  Are they useless combination?

Should I always go discovery board + ST-LINK? otherwise STM32-H407 + ARM-USB-TINY-H?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine it should work, the '407 is used on tbe discovery board as well.  But you may have to identify the SWD pins from their correspondence to JTAG if only the latter are labeled (the mapping is trivial).

Comment: After removing virtual drive Daemon, when connected it looks like running demo program inside memory.  Then I updated driver in device manager as instructed.  It works now.

Comment: I have an Olimex e407 board and I have programmed it with a ST link JTAG (the white and blue one) connected directly to the jtag connector and I've also programmed it with the one from adafruit and both work fine ... maybe you're connecting it to the wrong connector? have you verified the pinout for the connector and the jtag?